# Why does my Silverlight BusyIndicator stay invisible after setting IsBusy = true?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, busyindicator

My BusyIndicator works as expected when the DomainDataSource fetches data. But the control stays invisible when I set IsBusy to true in code.

I'm using Silverlight 4 and the toolkit BusyIndicator. In XAML I have bound the BusyIndicator.IsBusy property to the IsBusy property of my DomainDataSource control. The BusyIndicator control wraps my main Grid (LayoutRoot) and all child controls.

```
<toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding ElementName=labSampleDomainDataSource, Path=IsBusy}"  Name="busyIndicator1">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

</Grid>
</toolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

The problem is that the BusyIndicator does not show when I set busyIndicator1 = true; in a button click event. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you remove the Binding?

Comment: The BusyIndicator still does not show when I remove the binding. But the UI DOES seem to be locked/disabled until my button click event ends. Also, I noticed if I comment out IsBusy = false; (leaving IsBusy = true;) then the BusyIndicator DOES appear AFTER the click event code finishes. Of course, the BI never goes away either and my program is useless. I don't understand why it's behaving this way.

Comment: Seems to be a layout issue. Is the BusyIndicator at the root of your Silverlight application? Or can you post your whole XAML?

Comment: BusyIndicator is the first control just below the <navigation:Page element. Perhaps it is not possible to turn IsBusy on and off in one event handler. When I remove the binding and instead use the DomainDataSource LoadingData and LoadedData events everything works. I set the BusyIndicator to true in LoadingData and it appears and then set it to false in LoadedData and it disappears. I'm used to turning an hour glass on and off in a single Windows Forms button click event. Does the UI behave differently in Silverlight? It seems like I need a Silverlight click_finished event to make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The UI updates itself quite naturally on the UI Thread.  Events for things like button clicks also run on the UI thread.

In some cases property changes and method calls into controls will result in a method being dispatched to the UI thread.  What this means is that the method to be invoked will not actually occur until the UI thread becomes available to execute it (and anything else already queued up has been executed).  `IsBusy` falls into this category.

Only when your code has finished with the UI thread will the UI get a chance to update its appeareance.  You should not be doing any long running tasks in the UI thread.  In your case you tie up the thread to do your own bidding and leave the UI starved of this one thread it can use to get its work done.

Instead you should look to use the `BackgroundWorker` class and do all the heavy work in its `DoWork` event which runs on a different thread.

```
myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isbusyindicator1.IsBusy = true;
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (s, args) =>
    {
       //Stuff that takes some time
    };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
         isbusyindicator1.IsBusy = false;
    };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Now this click event completes very quickly allowing the UI thread to be used to update the UI whilst the actual work is done on a background thread.  When completed the IsBusy is cleared.

Comment: Thanks! Excellent explanation - I've marked it as the answer. But it raises new questions as to what time consuming task is allowed with the BackgroundWorker. I'm attempting to call ((IEditableCollectionView)DomainDataSource.DataView).AddNew and populate the returned EF entity with default values. For some reason nothing happens when I put that code in the BackgroundWorker.DoWork process. Perhaps I need to learn better way to pre-populate a DomainDataSource's new record. Meanwhile, I found I can start my button_click with this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait and end it with this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow.

Comment: @DeveloperDan:  There are too many variables in there for a sensible answer. There are two basic priniciples to keep in balance, keep heavy computation and blocking operations off the UI Thread and mutate the UI itself on the UI thread.  Once you get into all this DomainData, View and EF stuff things get hairy if you aren't using them in the pattern intended.